# Why no bracha on fasting?

Tags: blessing, fast-days

Fasting is a commandment. At first blush it seems like a negative commandment, but the Biblical commandment is to afflict our souls (on Yom Kippur), and fasting is one way we do that.  So, that fasting seems like it is done to fulfill a positive commandment.  In any case, why no bracha on fasting ("asher kidshanu bemitzvotav ...") on the various fast days, full and half day?

Comment: When would you say the blessing?

Comment: Rambam counts both a positive and negative commandment regarding fasting http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3300.htm

Comment: @YehudaW Even though it is a positive commandment, it is still not an action.

Comment: Perhaps there is no Bracha as it is possible for one to break the fast and then the Bracha will be L'vatala. Also perhaps there is no Bracha on an affliction.

Comment: @DoubleAA I would think the bracha would be said before beginning the fast.  We add Aneinu to the amida during or even before we begin a fast, even tho we might break the fast. Do you have an argument for saying the bracha at the completion of the fast?

Comment: I have no argument for saying a bracha at any point of the fast since this is a don't-do commandment so it doesn't get a blessing. The fact that you have no clue when to say a blessing is exactly because there is no point where you can define the action of the mitzva, since there is no action. It's the same reason you don't say a blessing every time you refrain from turning on a light on Shabbat.

Comment: @YehudaW BTW most Ashkenazim at least don't say Aneinu if they suspect they may have to break their fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As R. Yosef ben Platt writes [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80590/8775), a mitsvah which is observed through inactivity, does not get a blessing.

Answer (score -1):

There is no action being done.

Comment: The mitzva is to afflict our souls. That seems like a positive action. Why no bracha on that, whatever way we do so?

Comment: Could you [edit] in a source or reasoning that this is the explanation?