# When do we say a bracha on performing a mitzva and when not?

Tags: halacha, blessing, halacha-theory

There is no bracha on visiting the sick.  When and why do we perform a mitzva without saying a bracha?  What is the logic or source behind performing some certain mitzvot without saying a bracha?  Is there a unifying theme or does the reason vary for various mitzvot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was asked by [R. Avraham Av Bet Din](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_Isaac_of_Narbonne) to R. Yosef ben Platt. To make a very long story short, R. Platt responds that there is not a single determinant for whether a mitsvah warrants a blessing. This is (an elided version of) R. Platt's response as quoted by [Abudirham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Abudirham) (Birkhot HaMitsvot UMishp'teihem):

> תשובה הכי אסתברא לן דהני מצות עשה דלא מברכינן עלייהו לא תליין בחד טעמא בלחוד אלא כמה טעמי אית בהו. ... ויש מהם מפני שהיא מצוה הבאה בעבירה כגון השבת גזלה ורבית ... לא מברכינן עלייהו משום דלית בהו מעשה ... ואיכא נמי דלא מברכינן עלייהו משום דתלוי בדעת אחרים דרחמנא אזהר לאהנויי להו. והואיל ואיפשר דמימנעי מההיא הנאה או דמחלי לי' ומיעקר ליה עשה לא מברכינן עלייהו.  וכן לא מברכינן על ד' מיתות ב"ד ולא על מלקות דקוב"ה חס על בריותיו ... והוא הדין לבקור חולים ולשים שלום בין אדם לחברו ותנחומי אבלים שאין מברך לנחם אבלים ולשים שלום ולבקר חולים דהא בידיהו למעקרא להאי מצוה... ומנא לן דכל מצות עשה דאפשר למיעקרא אף על גב דאכתי לא מתעקרא כמאן דמתעקרא דמיא

In short, there are several reasons why a mitsvah may not have a blessing.

1. It stems from a sin, such as returning a stolen object. This reason even to something that is not an actual sin, but contains a tragic element, such as mandated executions.
2. It lacks an action, such as the mitsvah of pe'ah.
3. It is possible for it to be uprooted, such as interpersonal mitsvot in which the subject can decline the services mandated by the mitsvah. R. Platt says that this is the reason that there is no blessing on visiting the sick.